# nfc antenna coil wth external capcitor

Tags: antenna, coil, nfc, pcb-antenna

I have a NFC chip [Mifare Desfire EV1] which has input capacitance of **17 pF**(pico farad).

I got ready-made antenna ([Datasheet of Antenna](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/3/ANFCA-1510-A02-474022.pdf)) which has induction of **1.8 uH**(Micro Henries).
So by simple formulae when i attach chip to antenna it resonates at **28.77 MHz**(MegaHertz).

But I need it to resonate at **13.56MHz**. So i am thinking of attaching a capacitor.

So my question is :

> To resonate at 13.56MHz, Do I need to add 59pF  capacitor parallel to Chip and antenna.
>
> Why 59pF :
>
> 17pF of chip + 59pF c1 => 76pF which gives 13.56MHz

Comment: Have you checked the reference matching circuit provided in the datasheet? There's more to it than a simple resonant frequency calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Antenna is good because of challenge to obtain accuracy of L and C.

Note that this loop antenna is designed for two-way or Duplex mode of transmitter (Tx) and Receiver (Rx).  Each passive part can affect tuning as well as proximity to ground and connection wire impedance.

Note that the final values of radio filter design are critically affected by physical layout geometry.

C1, C2 below are essential to the operation and should be C0G type or equivalent quality capacitors for temperature stability.  Note that a good balanced design is used so the C values are split into two values.  Balance makes common mode noise rejection possible.

### [image]

Originally I said..

Did you use two 33pF for series resonance as specified?

That is the proper mode, not parallel resonance. Ground proximity will affect tuning.

Did you make solder contacts?

The other parts provide EMC notches.

Comment: No i havent use any capacitor yet. Are you sure about Series resonance? and yes i made solder contacts.

Comment: ohhhh now i get it. Thank You Tony Stewart. I will try and let you know the output. Thank you so much

Comment: so basically i have to add 33pf capacitor at tx1 and tx2 right ?

Comment: hey i used 33pf cap. in series n parallel but dint work. then i used 56pf cap. and the chip started working but at very less distance. like i literally had to touch the receivers antenna. Any suggestions ?????

Comment: a lot of unknowns in your description, layout and part numbers